# Vuejs Vuex sometimes initial state not working Error: [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Any_Variable' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex

Other pages are working fine. Only facing issue with this file. May be I am coding wrong.
Store file is included in app.js file as other pages are working I have not included it.
**Here Sometimes I get undefined MDU_Number. Sometimes it work fine. I am new to vue js.**
Image of error that I am receving:
[image]
This is my vue template

```
<div class="card-body">
   <div class="form-group row">
       <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">MDU Number</label>
           <div class="col">
                <input
                     name="MDU_Number"
                     :value="mduprofile.MDU_Number"
                     @input="updateMDUNumber"
                     type="text"
                     class="form-control"
                     placeholder="Enter MDU Number Ex:GJXXCHXXXX"
                     required
                  />
            </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 
 <script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
  data() {
    return {         
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchForMDU();
  },
  destroyed() {
    this.resetState();
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters("MDUSingle", [
      "loading",
      "country",
      "area",
      "product",
      "mduprofile",
    ]),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions("MDUSingle", [
      "resetState",
      "fetchForMDU",
      "storeMDU",
      "setMDUNumber",          
    ]),
    submitForm() {
      this.storeMDU()
        .then(() => {
          this.resetState();
          this.$eventHub.$emit(
            "create-success",
            "Created",
            "MDU created successfully"
          );
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
    updateMDUNumber(e) {
      this.setMDUNumber(e.target.value);
    },    
  },
};
</script>
```

This is store file name single.js and I have included it in app.js file
MDU_Number should go for null value but it goes for undefined. So I think it is not initialized properly. There are many other variables but for simplicity purpose I have included only one.
What can be the issue?

```
function initialState() {
    return {
        mduprofile: {               
            MDU_Number: null,               
        },
        country: [],
        area: [],
        product: [],
        loading: false
    };
}
const getters = {
    country: state => state.country,
    area: state => state.area,
    product: state => state.product,
    loading: state => state.loading,
    mduprofile: state => state.mduprofile
}
const actions = {
    fetchForMDU({ commit }) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.get('/get/detail/for/mdu')
                .then((response) => {
                    let detail = response.data;
                    commit('setCountryAll', detail.country);
                    commit('setStateAll', detail.state);
                    commit('setProductAll', detail.product);
                }).catch(error => {
                    reject(error);
                }).finally(() => {
                    resolve();
                });
        });
    },
    storeMDU({ commit, state, dispatch }) {
        commit('setLoading', true);
        dispatch('Alert/resetState', null, { root: true });
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let params = _.cloneDeep(state.mduprofile);
            axios.post('/save-mdu-profile', params)
                .then((response) => {
                    resolve();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    commit('setLoading', false);
                    let message = error.response.data.message || error.message;
                    let errors = error.response.data.errors;
                    dispatch('Alert/setAlert',
                        { message: message, errors: errors, color: danger },
                        { root: true });
                    reject(error);
                }).finally(() => {
                    commit('setLoading', false);
                });
        });
    },
    fetchData({ commit }, value) {
        axios.get('/mdu/profile/' + value)
            .then((response) => {
                commit('setAll', response.data.mdu);
            }).catch(error => {

            }).finally(() => {

            });

    },
    updateMDU({ commit, state, dispatch }) {
        commit('setLoading', true);
        dispatch('Alert/setAlert', null, { root: true });
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let params = _.cloneDeep(state.mduprofile);
            axios.put('/update-mdu-profile/' + params.MDU_Id, params)
                .then((response) => {
                    resolve();
                }).catch(error => {
                    let message = error.response.data.message || error.message;
                    let errors = error.response.data.errors;
                    dispatch('Alert/setAlert',
                        { message: message, errors: errors, color: danger },
                        { root: true });
                    commit('setLoading', false);
                    reject(error);
                }).finally(() => {
                    commit('setLoading', false);
                });
        });
    },
    resetState({ commit }) {
        commit('resetState');
    },
    setMDUNumber({ commit }, value) {
        commit('setMDUNumber', value);
    }
}
const mutations = {
    resetState(state) {
        state = Object.assign(state, initialState());
    },
    setLoading(state, loading) {
        state.loading = loading;
    },
    setCountryAll(state, items) {
        state.country = items
    },
    setStateAll(state, items) {
        state.area = items;
    },
    setProductAll(state, items) {
        state.product = items;
    },
    setAll(state, items) {
        state.mduprofile = items;
    },
    setMDUNumber(state, value) {
        state.mduprofile.MDU_Number = value;
    },
    setCountry(state, value) {
        state.mduprofile.Country = value;
    },
    setState(state, value) {
        state.mduprofile.State = value;
    },
    setProduct(state, value) {
        state.mduprofile.Product = value;
    }        
}

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: initialState,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

Comment: Can you add the full error message?

Comment: @Frnak I have added the image for error. can you please check?

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, it looks fine to me. I do not see any problem from a first glance. I can only propose two thtings to try:  1. install vue dev tools and check that the store and the corresponding getter for mduprofile are providing the correct data (in order to test you might need to hide the error causing template code). 2. instead of assigning `state: initialState` try `state: initialState()` - I usually don't assign it as function (if you don't reuse there is no need to). Maybe there is a delay in instantiation by doing so? Hope that helps you

Comment: Thanks @Frnak I will try your provided guidance. I am finding it difficult because the error does not come every time. But when error comes whole template is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking somewhere where you change this values, if you don't catch error properly you may encounter empty states.